# VSCode & Flow - Go to definition doesn't work

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, ide, flowtype

I'm using Flow for my React project as well as VSCode.

In order to make Flow supports VSCode, i've installed the [flow-vs-code extension](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-for-vscode) and followed the setup guidelines.

The third step is described as :

> Set javascript.validate.enable option to false or completely disable the built-in TypeScript extension for your project

By disabling the builtin Typescript extention in VSCode. The 'Go to definition' feature doesn't work at all and is very time-consuming.
( Go to Definition => No definition found for ...)

If anyone succeeded to make the both work at the same time, i would be more than glad to receive your help.

Thanks for your time, Louis

Answer (score 1):

I use Visual Studio Code 1.40.1 and the `vscode-flow-ide` extension and have turned off both TypeScript and JavaScript validation.

I get IntelliSense and Flow type safety. I can "Go to definition" for a function, variable, Flow type, it works as expected. Try that extension instead.